# Gulp: run jshint on a single file change

Tags: javascript, gulp, jshint

on a large project i'm running gulp tasks to min and concatenate a lot of js files.

On file change, before rebuilding all the bundles, jshint plugin is run to verify any js violation.

Having a lot of js files the tasks take a lot of time.

I'd like to run jshint only on the file changed and not on all files that will be bundled... Any idea on how to do it starting from the task below?

```
gulp.task("lint", function() {
    gulp.src("./src/**/*.js")
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter("default"));
});
```

Thanks

Comment: google for "gulp files changed" returns https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-newer

Answer (score 7):

Plugins like `gulp-cached` are perfect for exact this task:

```
var cache = require('gulp-cached');

gulp.task('lint', function(){
  return gulp.src('files/*.js')
    .pipe(cache('linting'))
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter())
});
```

Comment: Great that I could help :) Please mark the answer as solved (green checkbox on the left) for further visitors :)